# Запуск другого установленного приложения через своё

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Вопрос такой: Как можно запустить другое приложения из своего? Допустим, при нажатии кнопки в моём приложении - открывалось бы приложение "Камера" или какое-либо другое, "Вконтакте" и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Это делается при помощи неявных интентов.

Вот пример формирования сообщения для последующей отправки через почтовую программу.

```
mReportButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Создаем неявный интент
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("text/plain");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getCrimeReport());
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.crime_report_subject));

                // Принудительно заставляем выбирать между приложениями
                i = Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.send_report));

                // Запускаем интент
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

А на [startandroid.ru](http://startandroid.ru) можно почитать теорию: [урок 22](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/59-urok-22-intent-intent-filter-context-teorija.html), [урок 26](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/64-urok-26-intent-filter-praktika.html), [урок 31](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/70-urok-31-zachem-u-intent-est-atribut-data-chto-takoe-uri-vyzyvaem-sistemnye-prilozhenija.html)